# Several issues when using woocommerce_get_availability hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Im trying to show an 'out of stock message' on the single product page for products that are out of stock.

I have this code in my `functions.php`

```php
function stock_catalog() {
    global $product;
    if (number_format($product->stock, 0, '', '') <= 0) {
        echo '<p class="mb-2"> ' . __('** Sorry currently out of stock **', 'text- 
   domain') . '</p>';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_get_availability', 'stock_catalog');
```

I get the following error:

Notice: stock was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php'), wc_get_template_part, load_template, require('/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php'), do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart, do_action('woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart, wc_get_template, include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php'), wc_get_stock_html, WC_Product->get_availability, apply_filters('woocommerce_get_availability'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, stock_catalog, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong Please see Debugging in WordPress for more informati in /homepages/17/d825330075/htdocs/mytheme/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5313

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to use the method "get_stock_quantity"

```
function stock_catalog($availability, $product) {

    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('** Sorry currently out of stock **', 'text- 
   domain');
    }

    return $availability;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_availability', 'stock_catalog', 10, 2);
```

More details https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_get_stock_quantity

Comment: Sorry but [woocommerce_get_availability](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/95abba7eeb420636ef2d30f556d1bacdde83a4e6/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L2055-L2062) is a filter hook, not an action hook.

Comment: @chappers Could you change the accepted answer? Because answer from 7uc1f3r is the best of the best. It's high skilled level.

Answer (score 3):

**Your code contains not 1 but several errors**

- `woocommerce_get_availability` is **not an action but a filter hook**
- `number_format()` does not apply here at all
- `$product->stock` **needs to be replaced with** `$product->get_stock_quantity()`
- `managing_stock()` must be true, otherwise there is no possibility to set/store a product stock quantity
- **echo does not apply in a filter hook**, return should be used instead
- The output should be assigned to `$availability`
- `$product` **is passed as an argument to the function**, so there is no need to use a global variable

So you get:

```php
// Change stock text
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {       
    // Managing stock is activated
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {
        // Stock quantity
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        
        // Stock quantity is less than or equal to 0
        if ( $stock_quantity <= 0 ) {
            $availability['availability'] = __( 'Sorry currently out of stock', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }

    return $availability;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'filter_woocommerce_get_availability', 10, 2 );
```